# statET eclipse plugin, JRI.jar not found

Tags: r, eclipse, rjava, statet

I installed statET in eclipse on mac.

upon run/debug, I get

```
init JRI/Rengine failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: JRI.jar not found.
```

the jar is definitely there in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rJava/jri
and the environment R_HOME is pointing to the right place
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources.

I read other posts, everyone else seems to have the jar loaded automatically.

what's missing in mine?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line like this in the eclipse.ini file

```
-Djava.library.path=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rJava/jri
```